# Why does x = df.index is different than x=ax.get-xticks() for twin-x plot in seaborn?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am trying to do a plot sharing the X axis, representing time (YYYYMM) and 2 y-axis one representing a count (for bars) and the other representing the evolution of a percentage.

Desired outcome:

[image: Desired image]

So I did manage to do the plot I wanted, but I am not really understanding WHY.

The following code is the one that generated the plot above

```
f,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))

sns.barplot(data=df,x=df.index,y='solicitudes',color=color,label='solicitudes',ax=ax)

ax2 = ax.twinx()

sns.lineplot(data=df, x= ax.get_xticks(), y='pctMalos',ax=ax2,color='red',lw=3,label='pct')

plt.show()
```

On the other hand, **this code**

```
f,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))

sns.barplot(data=df,x=df.index,y='solicitudes',color=color,label='solicitudes',ax=ax)

ax2 = ax.twinx()

sns.lineplot(data=df, x= df.index, y='pct',ax=ax2,color='red',lw=3,label='pct')

plt.show()
```

Generates this other image

[image: Broken Image]

As long as I can see **the only difference is that in one I "get the x axis" and in the second one I use the same x** (i.e. calling df.index, which works fine for only 1 plot)
Yet, the second one breaks.

I am also having trouble with x-ticks-labels, but I believe there is something quite basic about Seaborn that I am missing.. do you know what it is?

Thank you very much in advance to anyone who could help me!

Comment: In seaborn, a bar plot gets a categorical x-axis, internally numbered 0,1,2,3,... . This makes all bars nicely even wide and evenly spread.  On the other hand, a line plot gets a numerical axis, which in this case are some timestamps. Instead of `ax.get_xticks()` also `range(len(df))` could be used.

Comment: @JohanC Thank you very much !

Comment: @JohanC I have been trying again and there's something weird. All you said works fine, yet when I plot the way it doesn't work and I ask for ax.get_xticks() and ax2.get_xticks() they both give

array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])